# Counting the vowels from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I'm trying to do. I have some text and I'm trying to filter through it and only print out the TOP TEN words with the most vowels. This is only a portion of my code, but this is the only part that I keep getting an error on. The error I get is: unorderable types NoneType() < int()....and I get that error when i try and sort my words. (let me know if I am unclear or confusing) How can I fix this error (in my topTen function)? This is the little piece of code I'm talking about:

```
def topTen(text):
    words = textToWords(text)
    words.sort(key=countVowels, reverse=True)
    for ctr in range(10):
        print(words[ctr])

def textToWords(T):
    W = []

    for line in T:
        words = line.split()

        for word in words:
            W.append(word.lower())
    return W

def countVowels(st):
    ctr = 0
    for ch in st:
        if ch in "aeiou":
            ctr =+ 1
            return ctr
```

Comment: The only possibility I can think of is that somehow `words` contain empty string, so the loop inside `countVowels` didn't even run, resulting in an NoneType being returned. So you can print out `words` to see what's in there.

Comment: It wont even print words, it just stops when it gets to sort.

Comment: unrelated: you could write `count_ascii_vowels = lambda text: sum(char in b"aeiou" for char in text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').lower())`

Answer (score 1):

The last line of countVowels is not indented correctly.  When the if statement is taken the function will return 1; when the if statement is never taken (the word contains no vowels) the function returns None.  Re-indent the return ctr so it's outside the loop and I think the program will work.